# How to rename return key in keyboard to search text in webworks

Tags: cordova, blackberry-webworks

i am new to blackberry 10 webworks development..i have to rename the return key in keyboard to search text.

Help me with solution.

Comment: post your code that you have done till now

Comment: i have no idea to do in webworks.so didnt proceed further with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to change the virtual keyboard (VKB) type to be a different variant than the default.

The BlackBerry Web platform supports the HTML5 input type property.  Depending on how you define your `<input>` element, a different VKB will be invoked.

Here's a sample page you can use to test to see which VKB you can invoke:
http://blackberry.github.io/WebWorks-Samples/kitchenSink/html/html5/inputtypes.html